# Laravel repository pattern - error with relations

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am beginner in Laravel and php. I have in my project Laravel 5.8
I make Repositories paternities in my project.
I write Repository Base, Interface and controller.

I have this code:

1. BaseRepository:

```php
    abstract class BaseRepository implements RepositoryInterface
    {

        protected $model;

        public function getAll(string $order = 'id', string $by = 'desc')
        {
            return $this->model->orderBy($order, $by)->get()->appends(request()->query());
        }

        public function getAllWithPaginate(string $order = 'id', string $by = 'desc', int $perPage = 1)
        {
            return $this->model->orderBy($order, $by)->paginate($perPage)->appends(request()->query());
        }

        public function with($relations)
        {
            return $this->model->with($relations);
        }

        public function create(array $data)
        {
            return $this->model->create($data);
        }

        public function save(array $data): int
        {
            $model = $this->model->create($data);
            return $model->id;
        }

        public function update(array $data, int $id)
        {
            return $this->model->where("id", "=", $id)->update($data);
        }

        public function delete(int $id)
        {
            return $this->model->destroy($id);
        }

        public function find(int $id, string $order, string $by)
        {
            return $this->model->find($id)->orderBy($order, $by);
        }

        public function findOrFail(int $id, string $order, string $by)
        {
            return $this->model->findOrFail($id)->orderBy($order, $by);
        }

        public function getModel()
        {
            return $this->model;
        }

    }
```

2. RepositoryInterface:

```php
    interface RepositoryInterface
    {
        public function getAll(string $order, string $by);

        public function getAllWithPaginate(string $order, string $by, int $perPage);

        public function create(array $data);

        public function save(array $data);

        public function update(array $data, int $id);

        public function delete(int $id);

        public function find(int $id, string $order, string $by);

        public function findOrFail(int $id, string $order, string $by);

        public function getModel();
    }
```

3 AdRepository:

```php
    class AdRepository extends BaseRepository
    {

        public function __construct(Ad $model)
        {
            $this->model = $model;
        }

        public function search(string $query, string $order = 'id', string $by = 'desc', int $perPage = 1)
        {
            return $this->model->where('title', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')->orWhere('id', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')->orWhere('content', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')->orderBy($order, $by)->paginate($perPage)->appends(request()->query());
        }
    }
```

4. Controller:

```php
use App\Models\Ad;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Repositories\AdRepository;

    public function index(Request $request)
        {
            if($request->input('query') != ""){
                $adsList = $this->repository->with('author')->search($request->input('query'));
            } else{
                $adsList = $this->repository->with('author')->getAllWithPaginate();
            }

            return view('modules.ad.ad_list', ['adsList' => $adsList]);
        }

protected $model;

    public function __construct(AdRepository $repository)
    {
        $this->model = $repository;
    }
```

> When I run my code I have error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::getAllWithPaginate()

How can I fix it?

Please help me.

Comment: can you show `__construct` of your controller?

Comment: protected $model;

    public function __construct(AdRepository $repository)
    {
        $this->model = $repository;
    }

Comment: And add please `use` section

Comment: use App\Models\Ad;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Repositories\AdRepository;

Comment: add it to your question please - not in the comments

Comment: I'm  added in controller section :) :)

Comment: Ok, try to change `with` function to return `$this` and not `this->model`

Comment: Ok. Now I have: public function with(string $relations) { return $this->with($relations); } and $this->model->with('author')->with('author2')->getAllWithPaginate() - it's return me error: Maximum function nesting level of '256' reached, aborting!

Comment: you'll have to do "return $this" not "return $this->with($relations)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
public function with($relations)
{
    $this->model->with($relations);
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: this return: Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::with does not exist.

Comment: I've changed the answer

Comment: Now my code run, but it's not return values with relations. It's return only values (without relations)